# Conditionally open global p:confirmDialog with p:confirm

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, dialog

I want to open a global [`p:confirmDialog`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml) based on a bean boolean value. I would like to have something like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save}" 
                 update="@form" oncomplete="jsfunction();">
    <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure?" rendered="#{bean.boolean}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

But rendered doesn't work there (I wish).

Also, I don't want to duplicate the `p:commandButton` and use its rendered attribute to achieve this.

Is there any way to get this done without changing too many things? I have to do it in a lot of buttons.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know that this question is a bit old, but I was recently having the same problem with conditional/dynamic confirmations and none of the above solutions worked fine for me.

After some tests, I built my button using the attribute disabled (introduced in PrimeFaces 6.0) as in:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.myMethod} value="Submit">      
    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" disabled="#{myBean.boolean}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: which version of PrimeFaces' confirm has disabled?

Comment: I was using PrimeFaces 6.0,  but don't really know when they added the feature

Comment: Both disabled attribute and c:if solution work, but I prefer this one.

Comment: Since I didn't specify the version on the question, I'm going to mark this as best answer. They introduced disabled attribute on PrimeFaces 6.0. For older versions, check c:if answer, which also works. Thanks!

Comment: rendered attribute is not working, but the disabled attribute works. (PF 7.0)

Comment: Same behavior in PF 11: rendered attribute is not working, but the disabled attribute is working.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit hacky, but you can use a JSTL "c:if" tag between your commandButton and the p:confirm tag.  Because JSTL tags are interpreted earlier in the execution flow of a Facelet page, the p:confirm tag won't complain that its parent isn't a valid commandButton.  For example:

```
      <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.myMethod} value="Submit">
          <c:if test="#{myBeanBean.warningEnabled}">
            <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="#{myBean.warningMessage}" icon="ui-icon-alert"/>
          </c:if>
      </p:commandButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to try would be using your boolean value to render your `<p:confirmDialog>`

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save()}" 
                 update="@form" oncomplete="jsfunction();">
    <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure?" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" rendered="#{bean.boolean}">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"  />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

If that does not work for you the only other way I see is the two `<p:commandButton>` option you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Mmm thanks, but I don't know if that would work for me. I'm using that dialog for the whole application and I would have to control that the boolean variable is correctly setted in every case scenario. It's just some particular cases where I want to conditionally open it. Can't this be done? :_

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to conditionally render with a attribute on the `<p:confirm>` tag. Your going to have to use a boolean variable to accomplish what you want.  Initialize the boolean to false and then change it to true for the few particular cases the `<p:confirmDialog>` is needed.

Comment: Yeah...thanks...it's a pity. I'm thinking now on the idea of doing it programmatically somehow

Answer (score -1):

You must use visible instead of rendered. the code will be like this :

```
    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.save()}" 
                 update="@form" onstart="dlgWgt.show();" oncomplete="jsfunction();">
    <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure?" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:confirmDialog global="true" visible="false" widgetVar="dlgWgt">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"  />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

if you need the dialog be shown oncomplete, set the dlgWgt.show() in the proper event.

Comment: Where is the condition? That dialog is showing every time. Besides, the attribute visible is false by default.

Comment: the way I undratood your question, there is no need to have a boolean variable, the dialog is always hidden, but rendered, any button needs to display the dialog, calls the widget variable show() function. if the rendered is false (implicitly or using a condition), you never have access to it, because it does not exists at all (it is not rendered, so you can not update it by ajax call). and this is the way I handle the same case in my applications. I hope I've undrstood the question right.

Comment: `visible="true"` displays the `<p:confirmDialog>` on load, it is false by default because you want it triggered from your `<p:commandButton>` not at page load.