# How to conditionally display a PrimeFaces confirmdialog based on back bean values?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, conditional-rendering, confirm-dialog

I have a condition `{notificationSearchBean.tooLong}'. How can I create a button when if that condition is true, I want to show a confirmDialog and when its false the action will execute immediately. When the condition is true the confirmdialog is displayed  and I want it to function normally: If Yes is pressed, button action should be executed, if no, the call should be aborted. This is what I have so far but it requires two clicks for it to be correct.

```
    <h:panelGrid align="center" columns="2" id="bodyContent">
        <p:commandButton value="Start Search" action="#{notificationSearchBean.getAllNotificationsForQuery}" update="bodyContent" rendered="#{!notificationSearchBean.tooLong}"/>

        <p:commandButton value="Start Search" action="#{notificationSearchBean.getAllNotificationsForQuery}" update="bodyContent" rendered="#{notificationSearchBean.tooLong}"> 
            <p:confirm header="Please narrow your search" message="Number of records fetched is #{notification.size}. Would you like to continue?"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" >
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button"  styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close"/>
    </p:confirmDialog>
```

This doesn't work as the button rendered based on what was original stored in the bean but I want it to be the new value from the current submission. How can I change this so it does that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditionally open global p:confirmDialog with p:confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467840/conditionally-open-global-pconfirmdialog-with-pconfirm)

Comment: @MahendranAyyarsamyKandiar but I want the action to go through if the dialog doesn't open. If I do what is described in the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467840/conditionally-open-global-pconfirmdialog-with-pconfirm)  the action for the search search will never be executed as long as the `notificationSearchBean.tooLong` is false.

Comment: No. You can have two buttons like you do ***or*** have the rendered attribute on the confirmDialog. p:confirm cannot have rendered as mentioned in the link ***or*** otherwise use p:dialog instead with actionListener. in the listener method if(tooLong){RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('myDialog').show();");} else{//do regular action}. In the dialog yes button you would do the appropriate action again